# Center multiply strings and do not print empty line Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to print some text in center where the total width is 60 characters, and also when the gpa is lower then 3.25, I do not want to print the empty line.
It works ok, but it does print the empty line when `gpa` is below 3.25.

Can someone pls help me.

Is it possible to use one variable and center entire text?

```
first_name, last_name = input("Please input your First Name and Last Name: ").split()
gpa = float(input("Please enter your GPA: "))


honor_message = ""

if gpa <=0:
    print("GPA can not be negative or 0")
else:         
    if 3.75 <= gpa <= 4.0:
        honor_message="\033[1;31;0m Excellent \x1b[0m"
    elif 3.5 <= gpa <= 3.74:
        honor_message = "\033[1;31;0m Good \x1b[0m"
    elif 3.25 <= gpa <= 3.49:
        honor_message = "\033[1;31;0m    Satisfactory \x1b[0m"
    else:
        honor_message

    print("Some text some text".center(60))
    print("Some text some text Some text some text".center(60))
    print("Some text some text".center(60))
    print(first_name.center(60).rstrip(), last_name)
    print("Some text some text".center(60))
    print("Some text some text".center(60))
    print(honor_message.center(60))
    print("Some text some text".center(60))
```

Comment: `if mes: print(mes)` is what you are trying to do? Otherwise combine all the text into one string to print.

Comment: print mes = honor_message. text should be centered. if I combine the text, I dont know how to center it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test if the message has content and only print if has:

```
if honor_message:
    print(honor_message.center(60))
```

The `print()` function adds a new line by default. Even when your message is empty.